# Sufficient condition for measurability

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

Let $f$ be a real-valued function defined on a measurable set $E$. Show that the measurability of set {$x$ : $f(x)$ = c} , where c $\in$ $\Bbb R$, is not sufficient for $f$ to be measurable.

Comment: What have you tried ? Where are you stuck ? By the way, the question is ambiguous. Do you want to prove that if $\{x\mid f(x)=c\}$ is measurable **for all $c\in\mathbb R$**, it doesn't implies that $f$ measurable ? Or only if $\{x\mid f(x)=c\}$ is measurable for some $c\in\mathbb R$, it doesn't implies $f$ measurable ?

Comment: I couldn't understand where to start from. Here I am trying to prove that the condition provided the set {x : f(x) = c} is measurable doesn't imply f is measurable/is not a sufficient condition to show f is measurable

Comment: Please, read carefully my previous comment.

Comment: Moreover, by "measurable", do you mean Lebesgue measurable ? And where is $E$ ? in $\mathbb R$ ? (-1) for a such imprecise statement.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E=[0,1]$ and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the sigma-algebra of the subsets of $E$ that are either countable or their complement in $[0,1]$ is countable. Take the function $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ to be $f(x)=x$. Then $f$ is non-measurable: Indeed, if $c\in(0,1)$ then $f^{-1}(-\infty,c)=[0,c)$ which is not measurable (not an element of $\mathcal{A}$). However, $\{x\in E: f(x)=c\}=\{c\}$ when $c\in[0,1]$ and $\{x\in E: f(x)=c\}=\emptyset$ when $c\not\in [0,1]$ which is measurable in any case (because $\mathcal{A}$ contains singletons and the empty set).

### Edit

A second example, just in case OP refers to Lebesgue measurability only.

Take $E=\mathbb{R}$ and let $N$ be a non-measuralbe subset of $[0,1]$. Such subsets exist, due to the axiom of choice. Now take $f(x)=x+\chi_N(x)$, where $\chi_N$ is the characteristic function of $x$, i.e. $\chi_N(x)=1$ when $x\in N$ and $\chi_N(x)=0$ when $x\not\in N$. The function $\chi_N$ is a non-measurable function obviously. Now $f$ is non-measurable: the identity function $x\mapsto x$ is of course Lebesgue measurable and it is very easy to prove that the sum of a measurable and a non-measurable function is non-measurable.

On the other hand, if $c\in\mathbb{R}$ then $\{x\in\mathbb{R}: f(x)=c\}=\{x\in N: x+1=c\}\cup\{x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus N: x=c\}$. Now we distinguish cases:

Case $1$: if $c\in \mathbb{R}\setminus N$ and $c-1\in N$, then $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x)=c\}=\{c\}\cup\{c-1\}$.

Case $2$: if $c\in \mathbb{R}\setminus N$ and $c-1\in \mathbb{R}\setminus N$ then $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x)=c\}=\{c\}$

Case $3$: if $c\in N$ and $c-1\in N$ then $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x)=c\}=\{c-1\}$.

Case $4$ if $c\in N$ and $c-1\in\mathbb{R}\setminus N$ then $\{x\in \mathbb{R}: f(x)=c\}=\emptyset$.

So in any case, i.e. for any $c\in\mathbb{R}$, this is a Lebesgue-measurable set.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprise that the OP wish "Lebesgue" measurability.

Comment: @Surb I guess you are making a fair point..

Comment: @Surb but I think the edit handles the Lebesgue case too?

Comment: looks much better. Following your idea, you should better consider something as $f(x)=\arctan(x)+10\chi_N(x)$ so that you have $\{x\mid f(x)=c\}$ is always a singleton (it avoid to distinguish all cases you've made). Moreover, your argument : if $f$ is measurable, then $\chi_N$ is measurable is a bit sloppy. Indeed, $0=\chi_N-\chi_N$ but $\chi_N$ is not measurable. following my example, an argument as $\{x\mid f(x)>5\}=\mathcal N$ would be better. (+1) anyway for the effort.

Comment: @Surb the arguement is not that: it is $f=g+h$ and $g$ is measurable, $h$ non-measurable implies that $f$ is non-measurable. Nice modification to always get singletons!

Comment: I didn't say that your argument was wrong, but just a bit sloppy as written (at my opinion). Even if it's obvious, I would expect that you mention somewhere that $x\mapsto x$ is measurable (that's why I gave my counter example : a sum of two non-measurable function that is measurable). But this is indeed a very minor detail, and some people in the community will think that I exaggerate. But at the end, I always have in mind that answers will be read by many people from different areas / background / level, that's why I like to be the most precise as possible

Comment: whenever answers are provided instead of hints :-)

Comment: @Surb I respect that and I agree with that philosophy. I just wanted to clarify what my argument was. You are right, this can be phrased better. I will edit that part:)

Answer (score 0):

Let $S$ be a non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $S^c=\mathbb{R}{\setminus}S$.

Let $g$ be an injective function from $S$ into $(0,1)$, and let $h$ be an injective function from $S^c$ into $(-1,0)$.

Now define $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(x)
=
\begin{cases}
g(x)&\text{if}\;x\in S\\[4pt]
h(x)&\text{if}\;x\not\in S\\
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is injective, hence the inverse image of any singleton is measurable (since it has cardinality at most one).

But $f$ is not measurable since the inverse image of $(0,1)$ is $S$.